# angular 6: trying loop throw an object (via *ngFor) after choosing a value of a 'select'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular6

I'm trying to build a "quick order" component for ordering movies.

The first element is a 'select'. i get the results via http request and then render the options.

When the user is choosing an option of a movie, i need to display him another select which shows available dates. i need to render the select according to an object who got string dates as his keys.

e.g:

```
{
    "2018-07-19": {
        "00:10": "5b4f445da2c93e36c4f1a1ca",
        "01:00": "5b4f355ab6334b27fc031adb",
        "13:44": "5b4f43fda2c93e36c4f1a1c9"
    },
    "2018-07-25": {
        "23:00": "5b4f357db6334b27fc031adc"
    }
}
```

everything is working fine with the rendering of the movieList select and with retrieving the dates object. but when i add the html code of the second select (id=selectDate), i get an error.

[image: error]

Here is my code:
ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../services/movies.service';
import { ShowService } from '../services/show.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quick-order',
  templateUrl: './quick-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quick-order.component.css']
})
export class QuickOrderComponent implements OnInit {

  movieList: any;
  movieShowsSchedule: any;
  selectedMovie: any;
  selectedDate: any;


  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService, private showService: ShowService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.movieList = this.moviesService.getMovies();
  }

  onChangeSelectMovie() {
    this.movieShowsSchedule = this.showService.getMovieSchedule(this.selectedMovie).subscribe(res => {
      alert("we got movie successfully");
      console.log(res);
    }, err => {
      alert("we did not get movie");
    });
  }

  onChangeSelectDate() {

  }

}
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectMovie">Movie:</label>
    <select id="selectMovie" [(ngModel)]="selectedMovie" (change)="onChangeSelectMovie()">
      <option *ngFor="let movie of movieList | async" value="{{movie._id}}" >{{movie.title}} </option>
    </select>
    <label for="selectDate">Date:</label>
    <select id="selectDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" (change)="onChangeSelectDate()">
      <option *ngFor="let date in movieShowsSchedule | async" value="{{date}}" >{{date}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Anybody knows what is the problem? and how can make this code work?
Many thanks!

Comment: Do not post images to show us text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. Since you're using `async`, you should set `moveShowSchedule` to the result of the Observable not the Subscription, or easier still, don't use async.
2. You can use `map` to convert movieShowSchedule into a usable model for your view.
3. You should replace **in** with **of** in the `*ngFor`.

**COMPONENT**

```
movieShowsSchedule = [];

onChangeSelectMovie() {
  this.showService.getMovieSchedule(this.selectedMovie).subscribe(x => {
    this.moveShowSchedule = [];
    for (let key in x) {
      this.moveShowSchedule.push({ key, date: x[key].date });
    }
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<option *ngFor="let x of movieShowsSchedule" [ngValue]="x.date">
    {{x.date}}
</option>
```

I didn't want to refactor your whole code, but if you created an Observable bound to the change event you could then use switchMap to update a movieShowSchedule Subject.

Comment: yes. but i want to get the keys of 'movieShowsSchedule'. not the value..

Comment: and even if i change it to of. and change the {{date}} to random text like 'asdasd', i still get an error "ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: @codingnighter2000, did the changes help?

Comment: thanks. working on it. how can i "/* ... convert to an array */"? and what should i import? can u please provide a link for that 'map tap' thing?

Comment: `map` is part of rxjs which you're definitely using already if you're using angular.  I'll simplify the answer a bit.  I didn't need to get all fancy with the maps and taps.